# Serialize a C# class to xml. Store the XML as a string in SQL Server and then restore the class later

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I want to serialize a class to xml and store that in a field in a database. I can serialize with this:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
XmlSerializer xmlser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));

xmlser.Serialize(sw, myClassVariable);
string s = sw.ToString();
sw.Close();
```

Thats works, but it has the namespaces in it.

```
<.... xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

Will these slow down the deserialization because it will go out to those and verify the XML? I got rid of the namespaces by creating a blank XmlSerializerNamespaces and using that to serialize, but then the xml still had namespaces around integer variables:

```
<anyType xmlns:q1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         d3p1:type="q1:int"
         xmlns:d3p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  3
</anyType>
```

My question is: Is it necessary to have the namesapces for deserialization and if not, how to get rid of them? How do I tell it fields are ints so it doesnt put in "anytype"

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: If you're using SQL Server 2005 or later, you should use an XML column.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, these namespaces will not slow down the deserialisation.  Those URIs are not Web endpoints that the serialiser visits: they are just *identifiers* -- labels which happen to use the Web URI scheme in order to guarantee uniqueness.  You can safely leave them in.

Comment: How embarrassing is it to admit that I just learned something new from your answer? I always wondered about those namespaces.

Comment: @MusiGenesis, regarding your query, it is not embarrassing at all.

Comment: Thanks, I wondered why so many are going to so much effort to take them out.

Comment: I encountered a time where I had to remove namespaces. For some reason they were causing a 3rd party library I was using to crash. I never got to the bottom of why, as a future release solved that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Btw.. If you really need to get the default namespaces stripped out:

```
        XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(msg.GetType());

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

        var namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        namespaces.Add("", "");

        x.Serialize(sw, msg, namespaces);

        string s = sw.ToString();
        sw.Close();
```